# Can I change which phone I play with?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have just moved phones to an HTC one X from a Desire 510. Pokémon GO works fine on it but it has given me a new level 1 account. How can I get back into my old one? When I sign in with google, it just goes straight in without asking me which account I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I tried to put this all together in one paragraph, it would be hard to read, so I'll use bullets.

- Make sure that you have signed out of your old phone. If you have done that, make sure that you're signed into the same email that you used for your old phone. This is because with Android phones, Google is already built into them, so it may automatically log in for you.
- If it is signing in to your other account, you may want to quit the app, somehow make your account that you want to use the main one or active one, then try reopening it.
- If you're already signed in and switching accounts doesn't work, you may need to sign out with the current account and sign in with the correct one